# Array of images not built correctly

Tags: php, arrays

I'm writing a test and I want the result to appear after each question and I want it to appear as an image and the array of images should contain all the results of the answered questions.

if answer is correct: check.png

if answer is wrong: x.png

if answer is not answered yet: dash.png

the problem with this code is that first it shows what is expected an then it deletes an image I think the reason is that it's not storing the results of the answered questions.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $numOfQ; $i++) {
    $_SESSION['imagesArray'] = $imagesArray[$i] = '<img src="css/images/dash.png" style="width:5%; height:5%">';
}

if ($_SESSION['Answers'] < $numOfQ) {

    if ($result != $stdAnswer OR $stdAnswer == "") {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $numOfQ; $i++) {
            if ($i == $Answers) {
                $_SESSION['imagesArray'] = $imagesArray[$Answers] = '<img src="css/images/x.png" style="width:5%; height:5%">';

                for ($j = $Answers + 1; $j < $numOfQ; $j++) {
                    $_SESSION['imagesArray'] = $imagesArray[$j] = '<img src="css/images/dash.png" style="width:5%; height:5%">';
                }
            }
        }
    } else if ($result == $stdAnswer) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $numOfQ; $i++) {
            if ($i == $Answers) {
                $_SESSION['imagesArray'] = $imagesArray[$Answers] = '<img src="css/images/check.png" style="width:5%; height:5%">';
                for ($j = $Answers + 1; $j < $numOfQ; $j++) {
                    $_SESSION['imagesArray'] = $imagesArray[$j] = '<img src="css/images/dash.png" style="width:5%; height:5%">';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$_SESSION['imagesArray'][$j]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting your session when the script starts executing the for loop. Change this

```
for($i=0; $i <$numOfQ; $i++)
{
    $_SESSION['imagesArray']=$imagesArray[$i]='<img src="css/images/dash.png" style="width:5%; height:5%">';
}
```

To

```
for($i=0; $i <$numOfQ; $i++)
{
    if (!isset($_SESSION['imagesArray'][$i]) && empty($_SESSION['imagesArray'][$i]))
    {
        $_SESSION['imagesArray'][$i]='<img src="css/images/dash.png" style="width:5%; height:5%">';
    }    
}
$imagesArray = $_SESSION['imagesArray'];
```